# USRP2: Number of A/D Converters

Tags: usrp

Why are there two A/D converters on the USRP2 board if you can only use one RX
daughtercard?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the daughterboards do quadrature downconversion and produce
analog I & Q.  For those daughterboards we use 1 A/D for I and another
one for Q.